# List loaded IPython extensions

Tags: python, ipython

Is there a way to get a list of the currently loaded IPython extensions?

For example if I load the extension autoreload into IPython with `%load_ext autoreload` or by running:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.magic("%load_ext autoreload")
```

Is there any way to show that I have loaded this extension?

I have attempted this by directly accessing the input history with something like

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
hist = ipython.extract_input_lines("0:100")
```

But it turns out that IPython does not store inputs with magic functions here or in the history list accessible with `In` and `_ih`. Only lines executing plain Python appear to be saved.

This scheme wouldn't work generally anyway. If a script called with `runfile` ran `load_ext`, all that would be seen in history would be something like `runfile('script_name.py', wdir='path/to/wdir')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out by poking through the `%load_ext` code:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
ip.extension_manager.loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

To see extensions and active ipython config.

```
import IPython

def get_ipython():
  return IPython.get_ipython()

get_ipython().config.InteractiveShellApp.extensions
```

or via CLI

```
ipython --no-banner -c "import IPython; print(IPython.get_ipython().config.InteractiveShellApp.extensions)"
```